# Pascal Infinite while loop

Tags: infinite-loop, freepascal

I'm implementing a program in FreePascal in Win10(64-bit). The problem state:

**'Given a string, replace all substring `'child'` with `'childhood'` '**

or

**'Replace all `'child'` with `'childhood'`'**

I try this program

```
uses crt;
var s, newS : string;
    tmp, tmp2, tmp3 : int64;
    tmpstr, tmpstr2 : string;
    step, step2, step3 : longint;
    position : longint;

begin
        clrscr;
        write('Nhap xau : '); readln(s);
        //main mechanism

        while pos('child',s) <> 0 do begin
                position := pos('child', s);
                delete(s, pos('child',1), 5);
                insert('childhood',s,position);
                inc(position, 9);
                newS := '';
                for step:=position to length(s) do begin
                        newS := newS + s[step];
                end;
                s := newS;
        end;
        writeln(s);

        readkey;
end.
```

You can see that this part:

```
inc(position, 9);
newS := '';
for step:=position to length(s) do begin
        newS := newS + s[step];
end;
s := newS;
```

was used to try to cut off the while loop, but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Thanks a lot and have a good day! Thanks for reading this question thread! =)

Comment: Given the requirement is as you've stated, I suggest replacing your program with a call to [StringReplace](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/stringreplace.html).

Comment: This is homework I guess. What your instructor is hoping is that you will debug your program to find out what is going wrong. Do you know how to debug? If not, there is no time like the present.

Comment: I hope you are aware of the fact that the replacement `'childhood'` contains the search text, `'child'` and that this should have consequences for how and where you try to find your search text after you replaced it. Otherwise `'child'` will become `'childhood'`, `'childhoodhood'`, `'childhoodhoodhood'`, etc. ad infinitum. So do as @David says, and debug your program. It is an important skill and easy to learn.

Comment: FWIW, since the line `delete(s, pos('child',1), 5);`probably doesn't compile at all, it looks as if this is not exactly your code. Please **always** post the exact code (copy and paste) that gives you problems. Do not type it from memory or from view. Use **copy and paste**. How can we tell what is wrong with your code if we don't even see your exact code? The error could just as well be in the in the part you typed wrongly.

Comment: @Rudy_Velthius this is my exact code. I copy paste from notepad

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Anyway, how are you getting on with debugging. I have a sense that you don't know how to. If you don't become proficient in this skill then you can't succeed as a programmer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know it doesn't compile, and I also know how come it doesn't compile, and I did try to reprogram it so it does compile, but i don't succeed in making it compile. So, I post this post and try and get someone to give tips, or solutions, or... I guess something. It's not that I don't know how to debug, I just don't show the debugging code in this pile of code up there. So... that's that. I admit, it **is** a homework, but I did try, but I just didn't succeed.

Comment: You can't debug the program until you can make it compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one of the possibilities, not optimized but perhaps the easiest to understand:

```
oldstr := 'original child string';
newstr := '';

while oldstr<>'' do begin
  // analyze the string from left to right
  if copy(oldstr, 1 5)='child' then begin
    // match found, perform substitution
    newstr := newstr+'childhood';
    delete(oldstr, 1, 5)
  end else begin
    // does not match, go ahead to the next possibility
    newstr := newstr+oldstr[1];
    delete(oldstr, 1, 1)
  end
end
// now newstr is the desired result
```

The gotcha here was to not analyze again what was added in a previous step (child->childhood). The algorithm above (**warning**, I've not tested it) ensures that any single char from the original string is checked only once.